# Execute Groovy script with arguments from Grails app

Tags: grails, groovy

In reference to the question asked here

[How to execute a Groovy Script from my Grails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927426/how-to-execute-a-groovy-script-from-my-grails-app)

which works except ...how do I pass arguments ?

```
def cmd = ['groovy.bat', 'C:\\my path\\mysript.groovy']
```

for a script that is run from the command line like

```
groovy myscript.groovy -name params.name -project params.name
```

using CliBuilder for arguments and params from form submitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy provides a simple way to execute command line processes. Yo can write the command line as a stringm and call the execute() method. Example:

```
"groovy myscript.groovy -name nancy -project testproj".execute()
```

[More information in this link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management).

In case of arguments with whitespaces:

```
["groovy", 
 "my script with spaces.groovy", 
 "-name", 
 "nancy", 
 "-project", 
 "testproj"].execute()
```

Comment: I have to use a list because there are spaces in my path

Comment: for some reason this didn't work initially, before I asked the question.. but it did once I restarted teh grails app. Thanks