# Calling phantom.js from grails service

Tags: grails, phantomjs

I need to call a phantom.js script from a grails service to create a PNG image I can cache.

All of the examples I've seen with phantom and grails deal with using phantom for testing so I'm unsure on how it should be managed from a service.

What is best pracice when calling a script from a grails service?

Its using a custom script to create the image based on a url thats passed in.

Here would be the equivelant on the command line :

./phantomjs createImage.js http://www.toBeConcerted.com output.png

Comment: You want to run a phantom script? Can you be more specific on your use case? Maybe services aren't the best place.

Comment: I've added the command line equivelent to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same as calling an executable from Java or Groovy.

Groovy docs have [a specific page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy) for this topic. And you can check also [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927426/how-to-execute-a-groovy-script-from-my-grails-app).

#### Groovy Example

```
def command = """phantomjs createImage.js http://www.toBeConcerted.com output.png"""// Create the String
def proc = command.execute()                 // Call *execute* on the string
proc.waitFor()                               // Wait for the command to finish
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at the WebDriver implementation for PhantomJS which name is [Ghost Driver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver)
It is included in `PhantomJS 1.9+` and can be called easily from Grails then